# awk - move first column in file to the last column

Tags: awk

I am trying to move the first column of a file to be the last column in the file.

This is what I have:

```
awk -F ',' '{first = $1; $1=""; OFS = FS; print $0, first}' file.txt
```

This works if the file only has one row. If the file has multiple rows, it does not do anything. The file is with carriage return and line feed (CRLF).

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?OFS $1"\n":OFS)}}' FS=',' OFS=',' RS='\r{0,1}\n' file`

Comment: Why did you repost this [identical question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/627163/133219) that you already had answers for to a new forum? [Please don't multi-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/361691) in general anyway.